# jsoup parse without validation

Tags: java, jsoup

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.*;

public class My_Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xml =    "<span id=sectionLinesDetail>\n" +
                        "       <tr id=123>\n" +
                        "           <td>text</td>\n" +
                        "       </tr>\n" +
                        "</span>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml);
        Elements e_span = doc.select("span[id=sectionLinesDetail]");
        System.out.println(e_span);
    }
}
```

I would like to have result like this:

> < span id=sectionLinesDetail>
>     < tr id=123>
>         < td>text< /td>
>     < /tr>
>   < /span>

but what I get is like this

> < span id=sectionLinesDetail>
>     text
>   < /span>

Is there anyway to skip the validation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [**`Xml Parser`**](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#xmlParser%28%29) is what you need here.

You only have to change the parse line to this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

I've changed your code a bit, but the point of the matter is only this line - everything else is cosmetic.

```
String xml = "<span id=sectionLinesDetail>\n"
        + "       <tr id=\"123\">\n"
        + "           <td>text</td>\n"
        + "       </tr>\n"
        + "</span>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser()); // The line as mentioned above
Element span = doc.select("span#sectionLinesDetail").first(); // the '#' means "with id"


System.out.println(span);
```

**Output:**

```
<span id="sectionLinesDetail"> 
 <tr id="123"> 
  <td>text</td> 
 </tr> </span>
```